# Windows form application command line arguments

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line-arguments

I have searched through Google and here found many examples but I can't seem to get my Windows Form application to run and take arguments form the command line. I really want to have the option of scheduling the application without having a console version. But every time I setup the cmd line arguments it errors out with a  CLR20r3 error.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   if(args != null && args.Length > 0)
   {
      /*
      * arg[1] = Backup Location *require
      * arg[2] = Log File - Enable if present *optional
      * arg[3] = Debug Messages - Enabled if present *optional
      * arg[4] = Backup Type - Type to perform *required
      */

   }
   else
   {
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.Automatic);
     Application.Run(new Form1());
   }
}
```

Anytime I try to pass an arg it errors ex

> myapp.exe "C:\Backup\" => CLR20r3

Comment: Is this really all of your code?  I don't see anywhere where you **could** pass an argument, based on what you have posted.

Comment: What exception exacly do you receive? You can find it in Event Viewer probably.

Comment: @Brian no not all my code just the start of it to make sure I was doing it right

Comment: Have you tried debugging the app?  You can tell your IDE to pass command line args.  You can also dump the contents of args to a log file before attempting to parse it, to confirm that the app is receiving what you think it should.

Comment: Stopped working
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: sqlbackup.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 5283ec48
  Problem Signature 04: SQLBackup
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 5283ec48
  Problem Signature 07: 1f
  Problem Signature 08: 15
  Problem Signature 09: System.NullReferenceException
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID: 1033

Comment: T think you may actually be trying to ask this question. How can I create a WinForms app that runs as a forms app normal, but when given appropriate command line arguments does not required a window or access the desktop. Can you confirm this?

Comment: `System.NullReferenceException` because args in Main do not work for Windows Forms application, you should use `string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

Comment: @GaryWalker yes this is exactly what I am trying to do pretty much I want to pass the 4 arguments and have the app run IE as a scheduled task

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an example of the startup code I use in a project that runs as a form app or as a formless app depending on command line arguments.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BuildFile
{
  static class Program
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      int ABCFile = -1;
      string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
      if ((args.Length > 1) && (args[1].StartsWith("/n")))
      {
            ... unrelated details omiited
            ABCFile = 1;
        }
      }

      if (ABCFile > 0)
      {
        var me = new MainForm(); // instantiate the form
        me.NoGui(ABCFile); // call the alternate entry point
        Environment.Exit(0);
      }
      else
      {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note this only works because nothing in my alternative entry point depends on events, etc. that are provided by the runtime environment Application.Run() method which includes handling windows messages, etc.